# Definition of Ordered Pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is probably a more open ended question. Kuratowski's definition of ordered pair is that $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. This is basically just subset of a power set.

But say we have a probability space that has events A = {a} and B = {a,b}, and we ask whether they're independent or not. Sometimes this is framed as asking whether the collection {A,B} is independent. But we've ended up asking if the ordered pair (a,b) is independent.

Is this simply an artifact of the definition? Are there other situations where something just happens to also be something else that's irrelevant to the context? And, most importantly, does it even matter?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91034/can-zfc-prove-false-theorems-and-still-be-consistent-was-junk-theorems-fo.

Comment: That was enlightening; so basically it comes down to a 'type' mismatch.